# Load Image From Base64 String Using Pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, base64

I am trying to load an image using from a base64 string using pygame with `pygame.image.load` but I am getting this error: `TypeError: load_extended() takes no keyword arguments`. Here is my code (I haven't included the whole string because it's like 10k characters):

```
photo = """R0lGODlhRgBGAPZUAAAAAAAAMwAAzAArAAArMwArzAAr/wBVm..."""

pepeImg = pygame.image.load(data=photo)
```

This is the error I am getting with pygame.image.fromstring:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mikur/PycharmProjects/timer/dodge.py", line 25, in <module>
    pepeImg = pygame.image.fromstring(base64.b64decode(photo, 'UTF-8'), (70, 70), 'RGBA')
  File "C:\Users\mikur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\base64.py", line 83, in b64decode
    assert len(altchars) == 2, repr(altchars)
AssertionError: b'UTF-8'
```

Here's the code:

```
photo = 'R0utCnHtEERJ3qQo960xPQgArITgK1l.....33sYy+72+NudrGfXe1inzveVVABFSQBYIgIBAA7'

pepeImg = pygame.image.fromstring(base64.b64decode(photo, 'UTF-8'), (70, 70), 'RGBA')
```

This is the image im trying to load (its beatiful):

[image]

I used this webisite to convert it to base64: https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the string into a memory file, like this:

```
import io 
import pygame
import base64

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
photo = 'R0lGODlhRgBGAPZUAAAAAAAAMwAAzAArAAArMwArzAAr/wBVmQBVzABV/zMAADMAMzMrADMrMzMrmTMrzDMr/zNVADNVMzNVZjNVmTNVzDNV/zOAADOAMzOAZjOA/zOqM2YAM2YrAGYrM2ZVAGZVM2ZVZmZVmWZVzGZV/2aAAGaAM2aAZmaAmWaAzGaA/2aqAGaqM2aqZmaqmWaqzJkrAJkrM5lVAJlVM5lVZplVmZmAAJmAM5mAZpmAmZmAzJmqZpmqmZmqzJmq/5nVmZnVzMxVAMxVM8xVZsyAAMyAM8yAZsyqZsyqmcyqzMyq/8zVmczVzMzV/8z/zMz////VzP/V////zP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAUAAFQALAAAAABGAEYAAAf/gFOCg4SFhoeIiYZMOScoKI45SUxJk4qXmJmJSSghKCI4OSInOT1JTT05TJqsrYhMPCETnpCQIjyVSbiuvK1NjJ2jIiE5KI0ouJQ8PVC9zohPusWOndU4o5+4SaWrz96CULAhnsU4n9Tlnqc9SElP389NPKK1J8KkKOa0yJU9u/CumDByhI+GsWq0zOUgZ6oSDx5RAGriYcyTvVrHruUTkQ/SsUlJTEnMxClEpI7HikGq4fFRDXsn+jFpNjIRk1SOsJGz1wgURkfmUOrg0Y2VwElFX1WClRFlx6cKN1bsaBJFklYCmSB5mCypIIFcH467uLCjTxQGbXXEx/GRKk1O/2CZwGCChYm5JnIQHST3LgsMszgGTRmpcDm3J0idQOJVEZMTd+ni3XD3gokTqx5PvivrxM6pPY+9fGTwotUmRlvgtUvZbt2/JnDtkOx6Q4hhEzyOmsa7JTpcUlo9QWLigl3XsGHX3bEDMga7z03I6gSzNzHSj6713MsKCg/VdylHr+uXrnnk4U3Muk2QXtCgJ1hCmjHjSMTUEUxQJk/+eXTod/XnmgkSoLCeR4V9EpQxM8ggwwxIvKMJE8WRt99+A7Y2V3LhwcYeR6HxBBQkITT4YDs0XSIFD7DRVl5d4w0II392zXLgMVRVRIMHHjjoIITBXdKEX5ERSJcEdyG54f9mx9HVpCchZLDbU3oJlEMHMfQoAxE2FNGYIVC0uFp5rh3JAoDKHZekBMNYxBExlkzBxAw89kgEETIwdgmF/ZHpVwZzgUDXCei12KIEnlXTSClByolDnVviicMS9yHCA1376RcghwNicB5eSa42gQizJMqEhIMkAUKPJsogxBFIQOHEIY8ViuhDzkUQ3X4SSABCr0ZuSh6iEkyAJBKHJDFDBzJ40CAROBwBRJyE8LDaeTtMwgMO4C1plwQYCIokpjOy4CuSEUiwA2qFzAkCDDzeWQQOPOzAAyFMNPciBotJ2IQTUcBygnk08lcwwf6Z0OggUOCQpQcfBDEDCEUW9dj/BQRj9iU4SziHV8LJIWzXCTg0x267PPQIAwgy2CDDXyzs8JW1xvG3Mb7fjUskedAJOqlATjSRoiFR8LBsvEQE+9UOGG7Yw8JTBHyTQOFY+zGMLQrKQjL4JrIECB8gHSgGX73oWgsQ8RWLBA00EEJXPAy8qcf8ItGDZ/d+ZZNqLD9I8XNlO7kkXd0wEULbIACgeNuYyYkEueDOhURcITAQgARXybkxFC1gLEMMIFBsl+Y7Q1dCbF9JAEADJ0yggOKrZ14rXpa1sEoSqq9eeCJOQGbCDBxAfCbZsIjHoXhLTJFEA6s/lLviIXTD1V0n7BWFZ4oTgKyciXBuHAgdePC3/wlTxF26i5jxwDwAC6wPwACrzzoFFE9AAQQTjaq/OgMNuAPFyYZ4gr5MAIIY0CIE3lFTjJyEgR20wH2wawDbGtANAAoiIupjAJQccrPy4YAyiRoG+VrgnNrw7DkkXIDiJBCAxY2DggGD2hScsI0BBIAUIMCVDBmWr7kkxjOEcgIOYrQzYUlgAA2gQe4k8EKuMCFghCia61bHtglcpoNO6IGaqEO2IrWGXGqaS6/ctwAkDmCISGrB9lL3OtgxgC4yU0QUliC4xJiECZ0zmGpM+JxvMWAAZRzAHxtAF10l5gdMEBoTJqC4ARCAARIwDg8sWIhoaOoyb5LCCSQAHeWMJ/9A/ekVkpAEIFCi7SEgaMAAfPWtxiUiCisyIUzwWIL/8Cw9nvLWmWAkqCVl6i4kVCAIbJeIaPhjSZdJjCYlMzgWEAqURwqUzkB1yw2EEQO9ciAPhlYIVECAAsLijBRacDoN9QlmZSIQXpQkOONFBja9wgAPlqAVVHUzBQ8ogBU7aQIUPCE9WCsdMq8Jqk+GK0DRjI1WaLAxJlTAAAmogOBGxjnJZGpXyNyAp5qkJvEgCQQzwEFIZ0CDGdwApDjAwRBukDlDNOGhCTCAFVcwIyFaBjnP3BldKJYeuYEqdCAIAQ2GSlKSErWk9MFfshAQUwQgQEAmqOi1Ogko2NAAB1f/DSoBt1qiktIApCCdWElFaoSRljQJlSKEEmBqAAREzjUCLKKaSjlWs2J1CDS4wVe7OtarFvWr9AEBDr4kBSD0AKKIrQAFMFACtEVhBzNyJ23ocgO8FoGogf1rWcv61dDdBaih8wBDD9GEFFQgpglIbVutKDMnmO+WJyRPibBKnxLZdqS07aySOBM6oe4grYN4aQEQi9oCUMAF20vCbNIEskuWiKQi9WtJgcokQ1lzB0yQXyGcoAMLEBe1BqhAD/jyAyJtwHcDCiMot+otInEKL9xZhAUKgFoEQDSmFngaXwDaH9Xsxz9/MY+nPvVFnZInjoaQgg8egNoGQxQCPrAY/3hgRiRbFuyW12wSf+jCA3t+xQdsBW8C7JuAFLS0tJHDJXIYGDKo2tJF4nHlIJ7QhBGEeMT3fbAOgPCVHlQgBLUEVRiHXGH0aKqj5OGBdvkyAhITN8dNVQJfdACBCVjxoIMiF6D4palP8jNAv5TAE7vpY+Iy9b70hWgFKmjaBBRAohsmWEGpmbC6DOwvdMMABVLQg5MloQIh/i5iC5BfQlRguDGtwEzVi9BGA8qHnuolqGgqAftaYM1SKK2b6wtlNFfgxIdWLQIOoKS5HmeujU71eltnAAO82QcheeiTU0tf1Yb3BVGsgACIS+gCHMDKOtPQeDTEXLxM4AAIqHWrE/tw6bY2WLXgRYAFqDWFlwpa1CN+8wEcgAAKdLvbB6AABcId7nFz+wCHJrGD171pKMfUACnwShTm22kRfzfN9M23fYfrZBH729nuRuyZE/CA8XZT1s++9rvX/V12uzvN9m6wst1sgWR5t60QhXi/ax3xWWdcxBB3MIn7jdgH5JebU+jBxd+N2GUPt+VpbjnLF+7yZbe65iyX+c1H0APgCkLlBrAAs5ktbWYHXdpBN7oFin5aoTcdARAYutCnHtEERJ3qQo960xPA81MdwgcqsEDYVaABEpD97CnQgArITgK1l33sYy+72+NudrGfXe1inzveVVABFSQBYIgIBAA7'

output = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(photo))

pepeImg = pygame.image.load(output)

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(pepeImg, (50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @Mihkel I see. I think it's best to use a memory file here. I updated my answer with a working example